# Can't recover details from a Instagram Post recovered via Hashtag Search - error_subcode 33

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, hashtag

I'm trying to retrieve updated info about some Instagram Posts, recovered via Hashtag Search.
When I request the data of any of them, e.g. **[https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/{ig-media-id}](https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/%7Big-media-id%7D)**, I receive an error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' does not exist, 
            cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. 
            Please read the Graph API documentation at 
            https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph- 
        api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33,
        "fbtrace_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   }
}
```

I know that there are some restrictions for posts recovered via hashtag search, as privacy of the post owner. But the Id that is returned with each of the posts seems "fake", or have a completely different role in this case.

If I try to recover the posts of my Business Account, I can use the Ids associated with the medias returned normally in the request above, and the details are returned.

So my questions are: what is the Id in a Instagram Media returned from Graph API' Instagram Hashtag search, if not the Media Id itself? And how can I get recent versions of the post with this Id? I need it to update the media_url property, when it expires.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue. I think it is because you basically can not get information about posts found using hashtag search. They are anonymized.